# Use Google Scholar for searching words appeared within Keywords

Tags: search, google-scholar, keyword

I have two words which are "team" and "conflict". 
I want to search for all the papers that have these two words in their "Keywords List".

Note that the Keywords mean not the general keywords related to searching, but the inherent parts of any papers after their abstract.

Answer (score 0):

*Google Scholar* does not support such a function.

There are commercial options though: If you have a subscription to *Web of Science* (via your university library), you can use their Advanced Search option to search for the "Author Keywords"-field (abbreviated `AK`). At *Scopus*, the field would be called `AUTHKEY`.

As for a free alternative, [*LENS*.org](https://www.lens.org/) offers a "Keyword" search but, according to its explanation, it merely refers to the keywords at PubMed.